# What is "objectName" in Spring's ObjectError class?

Tags: java, spring, validation

The class [org.springframework.validation.ObjectError](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/ObjectError.html) has a method getObjectName(), which returns "the name of the affected object". But what is this name? The name of the class? An identifier like `SomeClass@732dacd1`? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For top-level objects, it's a name supplied by the initiator of the validation process. For example:

```
Foo foo = ...;
Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(foo, "myFoo");
errors.reject(...); // Produces an ObjectError with objectName = "myFoo"
```

For the nested object it would be a nested path, i.e. property name is appended to the top-level object's name.

In the case of Spring MVC databinding, top-level object name is a model attribute name.